# How do we prove that $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(t)^{2n+3}dt=\frac{4^n(2n+2)}{(2n+3)(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$?

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, gamma-function, beta-function

I saw this integral in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.04269) on hypergeometric functions:
$$S(n)=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(t)^{2n+3}dt=\frac{4^n(2n+2)}{(2n+3)(2n+1){2n\choose n}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(1)$$
I tried to prove it and got this far.

Given $$\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin^{\alpha}tdt=\frac1{2}\beta(\frac{\alpha+1}{2},\frac1{2})$$
We arrive at 
$$S(n)=\frac1{2}\beta(n+2,\frac1{2})$$
$$S(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\,\Gamma(n+2)}{2\Gamma(n+5/2)}$$
$$S(n)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\frac{n(n+1)}{(n+3/2)(n+1/2)}\frac{\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+1/2)}$$
$$S(n)=\frac{2n+2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}n\beta(n,\frac{1}{2})$$
And assuming that $(1)$ is true, we get 
$$\beta(n,1/2)=\beta(1/2,n)=\frac{4^n}{n{2n\choose n}}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;(2)$$
But I do not know how to *prove* $(2)$.

I tried to prove it by starting with $$\beta(1/2,n)=\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+1/2)}$$
But I do not know how to prove $$\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(n)}{\Gamma(n+1/2)}=\frac{4^n}{n{2n\choose n}}$$

Comment: Just set $t=\arcsin\sqrt{u}$ to convert $S(n)$ into a value of the Beta function. It is worth to recall that $$\beta(1/2,n)= \frac{4^n}{n\binom{2n}{n}}.$$

Comment: I guess the paper is the one born from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2123298/what-is-4f-3-left1-1-1-frac32-frac52-frac52-frac521-r/2130679#2130679

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I know how to get from the original integral to $\frac{2n+2}{(2n+3)(2n+1)}n\beta(1/2,n)$, but my point of confusion is on the derivation of $$\beta(1/2,n)=\frac{4^n}{n{2n\choose n}}$$

Comment: The integrals $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^n\,d\theta$ can be simply computed by integration by parts or the lemma $\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{mi\theta}\,d\theta = 2\pi\delta(m)$. They are typically involved in the derivation of Wallis' product.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio and that's the Dirac delta?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I edited the question a lot. Hopefully it's easier to understand now.

Comment: This follows easily from reduction formula for $I_n=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sin ^{n} x\, dx$ given by $nI_n=(n-1)I_{n-2}$.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh for all $n$? or just $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @clathratus: it is generally used for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, but the proof via integration by parts is valid for any $n$ with $n \geq 1$. For the current question I think $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice method to integrate $\sin t$ to an odd power is to keep one factor of sine, and convert all the rest to cosine (using $\sin^2 t = 1-\cos^2 t$), then substitute $x = \cos t$, $dx = -\sin t\;dt$.
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} (\sin t)^{2n+3} dt = \int_0^{\pi/2} (1-\cos^2 t)^{n+1} \sin t\;dt
= \int_0^1 (1-x^2)^{n+1} \;dx
$$
the integral of a polynomial, which you already know how to do.

This way, there is no need to know about gamma or beta functions.

Integrating the polynomial, we get
$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^j\binom{n+1}{j}}{2j+1}
$$
So we have to do some combinatorics to reach your answer
$$
\frac{(2n+2)!!}{(2n+3)!!} = \frac{4^n (n!)^2(2n+2)}{(2n+1)(2n+3)(2n)!}
$$

Comment: So instead of using the gamma and beta functions, how do I get to $$\frac{4^n(2n+2)}{(2n+3)(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$$

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: When you integrate the polynomial, how do you get the ${2n\choose j}$ term? When I integrate it, I get $\sum_{j=0}^{n+1}\frac{(-1)^j{n+1\choose j}}{2j+1}$ because I integrate the binomial series of $(1-x^2)^{n+1}$

Comment: I think the ${2n \choose j}$ term might be an error

Comment: Right, fixing it.