# Proof that $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}{n\choose k}=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, proof-explanation

I saw in [this paper](https://www.math.wvu.edu/%7Egould/Vol.4.PDF) the following identity: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}{n\choose k}=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$$
I have a [pervious post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2969391/583016) on an integral quite closely related to this identity, but I still do not know how to derive/prove the identity. I'm really not that good at combinatorics or evaluating series, so I don't know how to start, which is why I don't have any attempts to show you. Please explain your steps thoroughly.

Edit: I know there other posts on this series, but I did not get from them the proof I was satisfied by.

Comment: @m_t_: Equivalent, but not visibly enough so to merge the questions in my opinion.

Comment: "Binomial transform" are some keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Binomial Theorem says
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}x^{2k}=\left(1-x^2\right)^n
$$
Integrating both sides over $[0,1]$ gives
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}\binom{n}{k}
&=\int_0^1\left(1-x^2\right)^n\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\left(1-x\right)^nx^{-1/2}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac12\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\,\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)}\\
&=\frac12\frac{n!}{\frac12\frac32\cdots\left(n+\frac12\right)}\\
&=\frac{2^nn!}{1\cdot3\cdots(2n+1)}\\
&=\frac{2^nn!2^nn!}{(2n+1)!}\\
&=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}}
\end{align}
$$
Using the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Comment: I'll re-accept your answer once you tell me how (in detail) you did the last step.

Comment: $\frac{(2n+1)!}{n!\,n!}=\frac{(2n+1)(2n)!}{n!\,n!}=(2n+1)\binom{2n}{n}$

Comment: Wait where'd the $\Gamma(1/2)$ go?

Comment: $\frac{\Gamma(n+3/2)}{\Gamma(1/2)}=\frac12\cdot\frac32\cdots\frac{2n+1}2$

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=(1-x^2)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}x^{2k}(-1)^k$$

$$F(n)=\int_0^1(1-x^2)^n dx=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1} \binom nk\tag{1}$$

On the other side (see proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2074931/show-that-int-011-x2ndx-2n-over-2n1)):

$$F(n)=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)^ndx={(2n)!!\over (2n+1)!!}$$

It's a simple exercise to show that:

$${(2n)!!\over (2n+1)!!}=\frac{4^n}{(2n+1){2n\choose n}}$$

...which completes the proof.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2k + 1}{n \choose k} =
> {4^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}{2n\choose n}}:\ {\LARGE ?}}$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2k + 1}{n \choose k} & =
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}\pars{-1}^{k}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k}\dd t}{n \choose k} =
\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{n \choose k}\pars{-t^{2}}^{k}}\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{1 - t^{2}}^{n}\dd t
\\[5mm] & \stackrel{t^{2}\ \mapsto\ t}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}t^{-1/2}\,\pars{1 - t}^{n}\,\dd t}
^{\ds{\mrm{B}\pars{1/2,n + 1}}}\qquad\pars{~\mrm{B}:\ Beta\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,{\Gamma\pars{1/2}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over \Gamma\pars{n + 3/2}}\qquad\pars{~\Gamma:\ Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,{\root{\pi}\Gamma\pars{n + 1} \over
\root{2\pi}2^{-3/2 - 2n}\Gamma\pars{2n + 2}/
\Gamma\pars{n + 1}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
In the last expression, I used $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1/2} = \root{\pi}}$ and the [Gamma Duplication Formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm).

> \eqref{1} becomes:

\begin{align}
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}{\pars{-1}^{k} \over 2k + 1}{n \choose k} & =
{4^{n}\pars{n!}^{2} \over \pars{2 n + 1}!} =
{4^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}\bracks{\pars{2n}!/\pars{n!}^{2}}} =
\bbx{{4^{n} \over \pars{2n + 1}{2n \choose n}}}
\end{align}

Comment: This is great. Thank you!

Comment: @clathratus Thanks. $\displaystyle\Huge{\bullet\quad\bullet \brace {\mid \atop \smile}}$

Answer (score 1):

I was actually thinking about exactly this sum a few days ago, and found a few ways to evaluate it. I'm on my phone right now so I can't tpe it up all pretty, but I'll give the general idea.

*Method 1*

(-1)^k / (2k+1) = 1/i * integral from 0 to i of x^2k dx

Multiplying by binomial coefficients gives you that the sum you're looking for is

integral from 0 to i of (1+x^2)^n dx

A simple integration by parts proves your formula via induction.

*Method 2*

1 / (k + 1/2) = integral from 0 to 1 of x^(k-1/2) dx

Multiplying by binomial coefficients and summing you get that the sum is equal to half of

integral from 0 to 1 of (1-x)^n * x^(-1/2) dx

But that's the beta function, and if you evaluate it using the formula involving the gamma function you get the correct answer.

Notice that method 2 easily generalizes to the case where we replace 2k+1 with xk+y where x and y are arbitrary real numbers, and indeed to the case where n is any real number.

Comment: PLease see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/

Comment: Thank you, but as I stated in the answer it's hard for me to do it on my phone right now. If anyone could fix it up I'd be very grateful, otherwise I'll do it when I have some free time and a computer at hand.

Comment: Could you pick one that you prefer, and then type up the full derivation? I am just completely lost with this right now.