# Evaluate $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2n+2j+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Evaluate $g(k)$ if $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2n+2j+1}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2-k}}+g(k)$.

The well-known [Gregory Series](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GregorySeries.html),

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}=\frac{\pi}{4}\tag1$$

Let us generalize $(1)$ in terms of binomial coefficients ${k \choose j}$,

Where $k\ge0$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^{k}{k \choose j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2n+2j+1}=\frac{\pi}{2^{2-k}}+g(k)\tag2$$

Expand $(2)$ for $k=1,2$ and $3$,

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-1\tag3$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-2\frac{1}{2n+3}+\frac{1}{2n+5}\right)=\pi-\frac{8}{3}\tag4$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left(\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{3}{2n+3}+\frac{3}{2n+5}-\frac{1}{2n+5}\right)=2\pi-\frac{88}{15}\tag5$$

The pattern for $g(k)$ is not so obvious, I was not able to determine the closed form $g(k)$

Q:
**How can we find the closed form for $(2)?$**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We will make use of the identity
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\frac1{k+\alpha}=\frac{n!\,\Gamma(\alpha)}{\Gamma(n+1+\alpha)}\tag1
$$
which can be proven by induction on $n$.

---

The sum in the question is
$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{2n+2j+1}\tag2\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}\frac{(-1)^j}{n+j+\frac12}\tag3\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{k!\,\Gamma\!\left(n+\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(n+k+\frac32\right)}\tag4\\
&=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\int_0^1(1-t)^kt^{n-\frac12}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag5\\
&=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)^k}{(1+t)\sqrt{t}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag6\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\left(1-t^2\right)^k}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag7\\
&=\int_0^1\frac{\left(2-\left(1+t^2\right)\right)^k}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag8\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4+\sum_{j=1}^k\left(-\frac12\right)^j\binom{k}{j}\int_0^1\left(1+t^2\right)^{j-1}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\tag9\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4+\sum_{j=1}^k\left(-\frac12\right)^j\binom{k}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{j-1}\binom{j-1}{i}\frac1{2i+1}\right)\tag{10}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(-\frac12\right)^j\sum_{m=1}^k\binom{k-m}{j}\sum_{i=0}^{j}\binom{j}{i}\frac1{2i+1}\right)\tag{11}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\sum_{m=1}^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=i}^{k-m}\left(-\frac12\right)^j\binom{k-m}{i}\binom{k-m-i}{j-i}\frac1{2i+1}\right)\tag{12}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\sum_{m=1}^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-m-i}\left(-\frac12\right)^{j+i}\binom{k-m}{i}\binom{k-m-i}{j}\frac1{2i+1}\right)\tag{13}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\sum_{m=1}^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\left(-\frac12\right)^i\binom{k-m}{i}\left(\frac12\right)^{k-m-i}\frac1{2i+1}\right)\tag{14}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac14\sum_{m=1}^k\sum_{i=0}^{k-m}(-1)^i\binom{k-m}{i}\left(\frac12\right)^{k-m}\frac1{i+\frac12}\right)\tag{15}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac14\sum_{m=1}^k\left(\frac12\right)^{k-m}\frac{(k-m)!\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(k-m+\frac32\right)}\right)\tag{16}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac14\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac12\right)^m\frac{m!\,\Gamma\!\left(\frac12\right)}{\Gamma\!\left(m+\frac32\right)}\right)\tag{17}\\
&=2^k\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\frac{m!}{(2m+1)!!}\right)\tag{18}\\
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\phantom{1}(3)$: bring $\frac12$ out front
$\phantom{1}(4)$: apply $(1)$
$\phantom{1}(5)$: apply the [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$\phantom{1}(6)$: sum in $n$
$\phantom{1}(7)$: substitute $t\mapsto t^2$
$\phantom{1}(8)$: $1-t^2=2-\left(1+t^2\right)$
$\phantom{1}(9)$: apply the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$(10)$: apply the Binomial Theorem and integrate
$(11)$: $\binom{k}{j}=\sum\limits_{m=1}^k\binom{k-m}{j-1}$ and substitute $j\mapsto j+1$
$(12)$: reorder summation and $\binom{k-m}{j}\binom{j}{i}=\binom{k-m}{i}\binom{k-m-i}{j-i}$
$(13)$: substitute $j\mapsto j+i$
$(14)$: apply the Binomial Theorem
$(15)$: shift factors of $2$
$(16)$: apply $(1)$
$(17)$: substitute $m\mapsto k-m$
$(18)$: rewrite the Gamma functions as factorials

Thus,
$$
\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{g(k)=-2^{k-1}\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}\frac{m!}{(2m+1)!!}}\tag{19}
$$

---

$(4)$ says that asymptotically, the full sum from the question is $\frac12\sqrt{\frac\pi{k}}$, which vanishes as $k\to\infty$. Thus, the sum in $(18)$ must converge quickly to $\frac\pi2$. In fact, the sum in $(18)$ is the partial sum of the sum in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77607) whose limit is $\frac\pi2$.

Comment: $(1)$ extends [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2971459)

Answer (score 2):

Note that the partial fractions decomposition of the inverse
of the [Rising Factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) gives:
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {x - 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \left( {m + 1} \right)\,} }  = {1 \over {x^{\,\overline {\,m + 1\,} } }}
 = {{\Gamma (x)} \over {\Gamma (x + m + 1)}} = \;\quad \left| {\;0 \le {\rm integer }\, m} \right.\quad  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m} {{1 \over {x + k}}\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {\left( {m - k} \right)!k!}}} \right)}
  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k\, \le \,m} {{1 \over {x + k}}\left( {{{\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,k} } \over {m!}}\binom{m}{k}
 } \right)}  \cr} 
$$

So
$$
\eqalign{
  & \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \binom{k}{j}
{1 \over {2n + 2j + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \binom{k}{j}
{1 \over {\left( {n + 1/2 + j} \right)}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{k!} \over {2\left( {n + 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }} \cr} 
$$

We have then that the sum in $n$ is

$$
\eqalign{
  & S(k) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right){1 \over {2n + 2j + 1}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 2}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {{k!} \over {\left( {n + 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2\left( {k + 1} \right)}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {{1^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }
 \over {\left( {1 + n - 1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,k + 1\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over {2\left( {k + 1} \right)}}\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {{1^{\,\overline {\,n - 1/2\,} } }
 \over {\left( {2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n - 1/2\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{1^{\,\overline {\, - 1/2\,} } } \over {2\left( {k + 1} \right)\left( {2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\, - 1/2\,} } }}
 \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \over {\left( {3/2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)\Gamma \left( {2 + k} \right)} \over {2\left( {k + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( 1 \right)\Gamma \left( {3/2 + k} \right) }}   
 \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {{\left( {1/2} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } } \over {\left( {3/2 + k} \right)^{\,\overline {\,n\,} } }}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {{\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)\Gamma \left( {1 + k} \right)} \over {2\,\Gamma \left( {3/2 + k} \right)}}{}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   {1/2\;,\;1}  \cr 
   {k + 3/2}  \cr 
 } \;} \right| - 1} \right) =   \cr 
  &  = 2^{\,2\,k} {{\left( {k!} \right)^{\,2} } \over {\left( {2k + 1} \right)!}}\;\;{}_2F_{\,1} \left( {\left. {\matrix{
   {1/2\;,\;1}  \cr 
   {k + 3/2}  \cr 
 } \;} \right| - 1} \right) \cr} 
$$

where in the mid of the derivation we have used the identity
$$
{{z^{\,\overline {\,w\,} } } \over {\left( {z + a} \right)^{\,\overline {\,w\,} } }} = {{z^{\,\overline {\,a\,} } } \over {\left( {z + w} \right)^{\,\overline {\,a\,} } }}
$$
and at the end the duplication formula for Gamma
$$
\Gamma \left( {2\,z} \right) = {{2^{\,2\,z - 1} } \over {\sqrt \pi  }}\Gamma \left( z \right)\Gamma \left( {z + 1/2} \right) = 2^{\,2\,z - 1} {{\Gamma \left( z \right)\Gamma \left( {z + 1/2} \right)} \over {\Gamma \left( {1/2} \right)}}
$$

**Alternative Approach**

Actually there is a more straight alternative aproach through the Digamma Function
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(k) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {1 \over {2n + 2j + 1}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( {{1 \over {4m + 2j + 1}} - {1 \over {4m + 2j + 3}}} \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( {{1 \over {m + j/2 + 1/4}} - {1 \over {m + j/2 + 3/4}}} \right)} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)\left( {\psi \left( {j/2 + 3/4} \right) - \psi \left( {j/2 + 1/4} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,} {\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2j \cr}  \right)\left( {\psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right) - \psi \left( {j + 1/4} \right)} \right) - \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2j + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( {\psi \left( {j + 5/4} \right) - \psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,} {\left( \matrix{
  k + 1 \cr 
  2j + 1 \cr}  \right)\psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right) - \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2j \cr}  \right)\psi \left( {j + 1/4} \right) - \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2j + 1 \cr}  \right)\psi \left( {j + 1 + 1/4} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,} {\left( \matrix{
  k + 1 \cr 
  2j + 1 \cr}  \right)\left( {\psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right) - \psi \left( {j + 1/4} \right)} \right) - \left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  2j + 1 \cr}  \right){1 \over {j + 1/4}}}  \cr} 
$$

Since we can write (re. for instance to [this page](http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/PolyGamma/03/01/))
$$
\eqalign{
  & \psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right) = 4\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,j - 1\,} {{1 \over {4\,l + 3}}}  + {\pi  \over 2} - \ln 8 - \gamma
  = \psi \left( {j + 3/4} \right) - \left( {\psi \left( {3/4} \right) - \left( {{\pi  \over 2} - \ln 8 - \gamma } \right)} \right)  \cr 
  & \psi \left( {j + 1/4} \right) = 4\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,j - 1\,} {{1 \over {4\,l + 1}}}  - {\pi  \over 2} - \ln 8 - \gamma
  = \psi \left( {j + 1/4} \right) - \left( {\psi \left( {1/4} \right) - \left( { - {\pi  \over 2} - \ln 8 - \gamma } \right)} \right) \cr} 
$$
we arrive to express the sum as
$$
\eqalign{
  & S(k) = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \binom{k}{j}
\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,n} {1 \over {2n + 2j + 1}}} }  =   \cr 
  &  = {1 \over 4}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,j} \binom{k}{j}
\left( {\psi \left( {j/2 + 3/4} \right) - \psi \left( {j/2 + 1/4} \right)} \right)}  =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 4}2^{\,k}  - 2\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)\,} {\binom{k+1}{2j+1}
\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,j - 1\,} {{1 \over {\left( {4\,l + 3} \right)\left( {4\,l + 1} \right)}}} } \right)}
  - \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,\left( {k - 1} \right)/2} \right)\,} {\binom{k}{2j+1}{1 \over {4j + 1}}}  =   \cr 
  &  = {\pi  \over 4}2^{\,k}  - 2\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)\,} {\binom{k+1}{2j+1}
 \left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l\, \le \,j - 1\,} {{1 \over {\left( {4\,l + 2} \right)^{\,2}  - 1}}} } \right)}
  - \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,j\,\left( { \le \,\left( {k - 1} \right)/2} \right)\,} {\binom{k}{2j+1}{1 \over {4j + 1}}}  \cr} 
$$

Interesting the comparison of this expression with the one given by
 @robjohn

Answer (score 1):

(2) is
$$\frac11-\frac23+\frac25-\frac27+\cdots=-1+2\left(\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\cdots\right),$$
(3) is
$$\frac11-\frac33+\frac45-\frac47+\cdots=-3+\frac13+4\left(\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\cdots\right),$$
(4) is
$$\frac11-\frac43+\frac75-\frac87+\cdots=-7+\frac43-\frac15+8\left(\frac11-\frac13+\frac15-\cdots\right),$$
etc.

In general, one gets
$$2^k\frac\pi4-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}(-1)^j\frac1{2j+1}
\left(2^k-\sum_{i=0}^j{k\choose i}\right).$$