Evaluate $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4 k-1) 2^{8 k}}{k^5 (2 k-1) \binom{2 k}{k}^4}$
How to prove the following equality ?:
\begin{equation}
\tag{*}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(4 k-1) 2^{8 k}}{k^5 (2 k-1) \binom{2 k}{k}^4} = 372 \zeta (5)-28 \pi ^2 \zeta (3)\label{*}
\end{equation}

Some background:

(\ref{*}) is used to obtain a unique series for $\zeta(5)$ ( last equation here ), which is in turn used to calculate $\zeta(5)$ to extremely high precision (current record is 200 billion digits).
(\ref{*}) is a very-well-poised $2$-balanced $_9\!F_8$, so one might attempt Bailey's transformation on it. However, this approach has not yet been fruitful.
A proof of (\ref{*}) can be found in Example $\tt XV$ of this article, it is however quite contrived and complicated. I wonder if there exists more elegant proofs.

Any comment or suggestion is welcomed.

$$=\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{32(x+1)x^{2k}}{\left(z^{k}^{-3/2}\right)^4}dx$$ I'm not sure that I should go this way.

I'm looking at Example XV, but not seeing that exact formula. Are you saying that () can easily be derived from the formulas in Ex. XV? If so, you already know a proof of the equality (), so what precisely are you asking for in this MSE question? Thanks in advance for the clarifications

@D.R. Thanks for the question. This formula is the displayed equation just before Remark 5.3 of the article. As I think the proof there is complicated, I am asking for a more elegant proof on MSE. I know some users here are experts in producing clever/elegant solution to otherwise tricky integral/series.

Possible reference - https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2130679/1157207

As a suggestion, one might attempt to connect the series with the following integrals:
$$\color{blue}{\int_0^1 (2x-1) K^4(x)dx}-\color{red}{\zeta(2)\int_0^1 (2x-1) \frac{K^4\left(\frac{2 \sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}\right)}{(1+\sqrt x)^2}dx}=\frac{\color{blue}{372\zeta(5)}-\color{red}{28 \pi^2\zeta(3)}}{32}$$
Now after some integral manipulations we can also rewrite the original series as:
$$S=16\int_0^1\int_0^1 \left(K^2(\tfrac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2})-K^2(\tfrac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2})\right)\frac{\arcsin(xt)}{\sqrt{1-x^2t^2}}dxdt$$ Note that I utilized the Wolfram variant of $K(k)$ not with modulus $k$.

@Zacky Quite nice integral representation, you're very encouraged to post as a partial solution below.

This is only meant to give some ideas on how to tackle the series via integrals. I hope that someone can further build up on this and finish the solution at some point. To get a first impression, I'd recommend to peek at $(1)$, $(2)$ and $(3)$ directly.
We will start by converting the series into a quadruple integral by utilizing the following two identities:
$$\frac{\arcsin \left( x\right)}{\sqrt{1- x^2}} =\frac12 \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n x^{2n-1}}{n\binom{2n}{n}};\quad \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \sin^{2n-1}xdx= \frac12\frac{4^n}{n\binom{2n}{n}}$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{4^n}{n\binom{2n}{n}}\right)^4 t^n=\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\arcsin(t\sin x\sin y\sin z)}{\sqrt{1-t^2\sin^2 x\sin^2 y \sin^2 z }}dxdydz$$
$$ \Rightarrow \mathcal S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(4n-1) 256^n}{(2n-1)n^5 \binom{2n}{n}}=\small{32\int_0^1\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(t\sin x\sin y\sin z)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2\sin^2 x\sin^2 y \sin^2 z }}dxdydzdt}$$
Next, we will substitute $\sin x\to x$, $\sin y\to y$ and $\sin z\to z$ followed by $xyz\to x$ to arrive at:
$$\mathcal S=32\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^1 \int_0^{yz} \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(tx)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2 x^2}} \frac{dxdydzdt}{\sqrt{y^2 z^2-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
$$=32\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(tx)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2 x^2}} \underbrace{\int_{x}^1 \int_{x/z}^1 \frac{dydzdxdt}{\sqrt{y^2z^2-x^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-z^2}}}_{\mathcal J(x)}$$
$$\small =\boxed{16\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)\right) \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(tx)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2 x^2}} dxdt} \tag 1$$
Where $K(k)$ is the Complete Elliptic Integral of the First Kind with elliptic modulus $k$. Note that you need to put $K(k)=K(k^2)$ if you want to verify numerically in the Wolfram language.

Note that the $\mathcal J(x)$ integral from above was calculated as follows:
$$\mathcal J(x)=\int_{x}^1 \frac{1}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_{x/z}^1 \frac{dydz}{\sqrt{y^2-x^2/z^2}\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$
$$\overset{y\to \sqrt{1-(1-x^2/z^2)y^2}}=\int_x^1 \frac{1}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}\int_0^1 \frac{dydz}{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt{1-(1-x^2/z^2)y^2}}$$
$$=\int_x^1 \frac{K\left(\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{z^2}}\right)}{z\sqrt{1-z^2}}dz\overset{\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{z^2}}\to z}=\int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} \frac{zK(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}}dz$$
$$=\Re\int_0^1 \frac{zK(z)}{\sqrt{1-z^2}\sqrt{1-x^2-z^2}}dz \overset{\small \bigstar}= \Re \frac{1}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}} K^2 \small{\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}}\right)}$$
$$\small \overset{\small \bigstar \bigstar}=\frac12\left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)\right)$$
The $\small \bigstar$ result was derived by Yajun Zhou in this article, see page 19 under eq. $(47)$. Whereas the $\small \bigstar \bigstar$ identity follows by squaring $K(1/k)=k(K(k)-iK'(k))$ and taking the real part.

Now, the most intuitively way to move forward I think would be to compute the integral with respect to $t$, which can be done with the substitution $tx\to t$ followed by $t\to \frac{2t}{1+t^2}$, to obtain:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(xt)}{t\sqrt{1-x^2t^2}}dt=2\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)+\frac{\arcsin^2 x}{2x}$$
Where $\operatorname{Ti}_2(x)$ is the inverse tangent integral. This gives yet another integral representation:
$$\small \mathcal S=32\int_0^1 \left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)\right)\left(\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\frac{x}{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}\right)+\frac{\arcsin^2 x}{4x}\right)dx$$
$$\overset{x\to \sin x}=\boxed{32\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(K^2\left(\cos \frac{x}{2}\right)-K^2\left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\left(\operatorname{Ti}_2\left(\tan \frac{x}{2}\right)+\frac{x^2}{4\sin x}\right)\cos x \, dx} \tag2$$
I was quite optimistic about the above integral, especially since it allows to utilize various series such as $\operatorname{Ti}_2(\tan x)-x\ln(\tan x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\sin((4n+2)x)}{(2n+1)^2}$, but felt short in the end.

An even more promising idea is based on another article due to Yajun Zhou, which proves that:
$$\zeta(5)=-\frac{\pi^4}{372}\int_{-1}^1 x\left(P_{-1/2}(x)\right)^4 dx; \quad \zeta(3) = -\frac{\pi^4}{168}\int_{-1}^1 x\left(P_{-1/4}(x)\right)^4 dx$$
Where $P_n(x)$ is the Legendre function, defined via the Mehler-Dirichlet formula. Now, by rewriting $P_{-1/2}(\cos x)=\frac{2}{\pi} K\left(\sin \frac{x}{2}\right)$ and $P_{-1/4}(\cos x)= \frac{2}{\pi \sqrt{1+\sin \frac{x}{2}}}K\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\sin \frac{x}{2}}{1+\sin \frac{x}{2}}}\right)$ followed by substituting $\frac{1-x}{2}\to x$ we arrive at the following result, which surprisingly is identical with the result of our original series:
$$\boxed{32\int_0^1 (2x-1) K^4(\sqrt x)dx-32\zeta(2)\int_0^1 \frac{2x-1}{{(1+\sqrt x)^2}} \small{K^4\left(\sqrt{\frac{2 \sqrt x}{1+\sqrt x}}\right)}dx=372\zeta(5)-28 \pi^2\zeta(3)}$$
As such, it is reasonable to think that we can actually go ahead and connect our previous double integral seen in $(1)$ with the above result. Namely, to arrive at squared elliptic integrals in $(1)$ we integrated twice after essentially substituting $xy \to x$ and $xz\to x$, similarly we can expect that if we further substitute $xt \to x$ we will obtain third powers, and so on for fourth powers.
Anyway, continuing from $(1)$ we have:
$$\small \mathcal S =16\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2}}{2}}\right)\right) \frac{(1+t)\arcsin(tx)}{t\sqrt{1-t^2 x^2}} dxdt$$
$$\small \overset{xt \to x}=16\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\int_x^1  \left(\frac{1}{t}+\frac{1}{t^2}\right) \left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2/t^2}}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x^2/t^2}}{2}}\right)\right) dtdx$$
$$\small \overset{\sqrt{1-x^2/t^2}\to t}=16\int_0^1 \frac{\arcsin x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \int_0^\sqrt{1-x^2} \left(\frac{t}{1-t^2}+\frac{t}{x\sqrt{1-t^2}}\right)\left(K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1+t}{2}}\right)-K^2\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-t}{2}}\right)\right) dtdx$$
$$\overset{\large {x\to \sin x \atop \large t\to\cos t}}=\boxed{16\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} x \int_x^\frac{\pi}{2} \left(\frac{\cos t}{\sin t}+\frac{\cos t}{\sin \color{red}{x}}\right)\left(K^2\left(\cos \frac{t}{2}\right)-K^2\left(\sin \frac{t}{2}\right)\right) dtdx} \tag 3$$
Unfortunately, here I hit another dead end as I'm not sure how to further calculate the above $t$ integral, which I suspect that can be expressed as a sum of cubic elliptic integrals.

Maybe it's more direct to use $$\int_{0}^{1} x^n\left [
K\left ( \sqrt{\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x} }{2} }  \right )^2

K\left ( \sqrt{\frac{1-\sqrt{1-x} }{2} }  \right )^2 \right ]
\text{d} x=\frac{4\cdot(1)_n^3}{\left ( 2n+1 \right )^3\left ( \frac12 \right )_n^3}.$$


@SetnessRamesory interesting result, I was not aware of it.
