# closed form expression of a hypergeometric sum

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, closed-form, hypergeometric-function

After playing around with transforms of a certain parametric integral, I am inclined to think that the linear combination $$f(n):=\dfrac1{n-2}\left({\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{n-2}{4n},\dfrac12;\dfrac{5n-2}{4n};-1)\right)+\dfrac1{n+2}\left({\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{n+2}{4n},\dfrac12;\dfrac{5n+2}{4n};-1)\right)$$ has a closed form for integer $n$. I know for example that $f(3)=\dfrac{1}{12^{3/4}}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac14)^2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$. Any ideas?

*Edit*: putting $a:=\frac14-\frac1{2n}$, we can define $g(a):= \frac{8}{1-4a}f(\frac{8}{1-4a})$ to get arguments closer to the "standard" notation used in formula collections. The question then becomes:

> Which rational values of $a$, other than $a= \frac1{12}$, allow a closed form for$$g(a)=\dfrac1{a}\left({\,}_2F_1(a,\frac12;a+1;-1)\right)+\dfrac1{\frac{1}{2}-a}\left({\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{1}{2}-a,\frac12;\frac32-a;-1)\right)?$$

Comment: Can you include that "parametric integral"? I might be a clue to why the $n$ in my answer has closed-forms.

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII oh sorry, that was such a long time ago that I don't remember at all what that was and where it occurred! Nothing for f(24)? And it is surprising that nothing came up for f(10).

Comment: Actually, "apparently" nothing for $n<48$, though I did use a hundred decimal digits.

Comment: I guess you have already raised $f(n)/K(k_{whatever})$ to the 4th power to increase your chances?

Comment: Yes, and I assume that the $d$ of $K(k_d)$ divides $n$. So it was natural to check $f(5)/K(k_5)$ and $f(7)/K(k_7)$. Why the former is algebraic, while the latter apparently is not is intriguing. **P.S.** However, I've found that certain patterns using eta quotients may involve only $p = 2,3,5$.

Answer (score 2):

If we use the original function,

$$f(n):=\tfrac1{n-2}\left({\,}_2F_1\big(\tfrac{n-2}{4n},\tfrac12;\tfrac{5n-2}{4n};-1\big)\right)+\tfrac1{n+2}\left({\,}_2F_1\big(\tfrac{n+2}{4n},\tfrac12;\tfrac{5n+2}{4n};-1\big)\right)$$

then there are several other $f(n)$ with a closed form. Let $K(k_d)$ be an *[elliptic integral singular value](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)*. Then,

$$f(3) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3\sqrt3}}\; K(k_1)$$
$$f(4) = \sqrt{\frac{-1+\sqrt2}{2\sqrt2}}\; K(k_2)$$
$$f(5) = \frac{\sqrt2}{(\sqrt5\phi)^{5/4}}\; K(k_5)$$
$$f(6) = \sqrt{\frac{1}{12\sqrt3}}\; K(k_3)$$
$$f(12) = \sqrt{\alpha}\; K(k_6)$$

where $\phi$ is the *golden ratio* and $\alpha$ is a quartic root.

**P.S.** Try as I might, I couldn't find anything else with $2<n<20$ which begs the question what makes these $n$ so special.

Answer (score 1):

I have found two instances of $_2F_1(a,b;c;z), z=-1$ in

A. Erdelyi, *Higher Transcendental Functions*, Vol. 1 (and particularly, Sec. 2.8), Krieger Publishing.

that may be of help to you.

$$
_2F_1(a,b;1+a-b;-1)=2^{-a}\frac{\Gamma(1+a-b)\Gamma(1/2)}{\Gamma(1-b+a/2)\Gamma(1/2+a/2)}, \quad 1+a-b\ne0,-1,-2,...
$$
$$
(a+1)_2F_1(-a,1;b+2;-1)+(b+1)_2F_1(-b,1;a+2;-1)=2^{a+b+1}\frac{\Gamma(a+2)\Gamma(b+2)}{\Gamma(a+b+2)}, \quad a,b\ne-2,-3,-4,...
$$
And this one from the [*NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions*](http://dlmf.nist.gov/15.4), which is a variation of the first one above

$$
_2F_1(a,b;1+a-b;-1)=\frac{\Gamma(1+a-b)\Gamma(a/2+1)}{\Gamma(1-b+a/2)\Gamma(1+a)}
$$

There was one additional relation for $_2F_1(a,b;c;z), z=-1$, but it was in terms of the digamma function.

Comment: Thank you for searching, but this helps only for $_2F_1(a,1/2;a+1/2;-1)$, What I need is $_2F_1(a,1/2;a+1;-1)$. And the digamma one (15.4.27)  has 1 not 1/2 as argument.

Comment: @spanferkel I haven't had a chance to see if the case for $n=3$ you presented fits any of the solutions I found. I did, however, check that solution numerically. At any rate, my point is that there are only a limited number of *known* solutions for $z=-1$ and if these don't do the trick it's unlikely that you'll find a general solution for arbitrary $n$.

Comment: You say "it's unlikely that you'll find a general solution", and of course I'd agree if it was just about one of the two terms. But here is a (conveniently weighted) sum. I remember having seen once a certain  weighted sum of two order $n$ digamma functions with arguments $\frac{1\pm\sqrt{5}}2$ which had a closed form...

Comment: @spanferkel Apologies. I didn't mean to disparage your efforts, but merely to point out that such solutions are rare and limited, as evidenced by what I turned up in my own references.

Comment: Sure, I am just searching a needle in a hay stick... :)

Answer (score 1):

A specific relation can be found [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/07.23.03.0019.01):
\begin{equation}
\beta\,_2F_1(\alpha, \alpha + \beta, \alpha + 1, -1) + \alpha \,_2F_1(\beta, \alpha + \beta, \beta + 1, -1)= \frac{\Gamma(\alpha + 1) \Gamma(\beta + 1)}{ \Gamma(\alpha + \beta)}
\end{equation} 
Dividing this identity by $\alpha\beta$ and taking $\alpha=a, \beta=1/2-a$, we find 
\begin{align}
g(a)&=\dfrac1{a}{\,}_2F_1(a,\frac12;a+1;-1)+\dfrac1{\frac{1}{2}-a}{\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{1}{2}-a,\frac12;\frac32-a;-1)\\
&=\frac{\Gamma(a + 1) \Gamma\left( \frac{3}{2}-a \right)}{ a\left( \frac{1}{2}-a \right)\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\Gamma(a)\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}-a \right)\\
&=2^{2a-1}\frac{B(a,a)}{\cos(\pi a)}
\end{align}
where $B(x,y)$ is the Beta function.

> For a rational value of $a$, $g(a)$ can thus be expressed in a closed form using gamma functions at rational values.

A closed form involving the central Beta function at $a$  and square roots can be found if $\cos(\pi a)$ can be expressed using only square roots. This is the case (see [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Cos/03/02/), at the bottom of the page), if $a=r/s$ where $r$ is an integer and $s$ is the product of a power of 2 and distinct [Fermat primes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FermatPrime.html) $\{3,5,17,\ldots\}$.

To explore the link with the singular values of the elliptic integrals, using $a=(n-2)/(4n)$, one obtains
\begin{align}
 f(n)&=\dfrac1{n-2}{\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{n-2}{4n},\dfrac12;\dfrac{5n-2}{4n};-1)+\dfrac1{n+2}{\,}_2F_1(\dfrac{n+2}{4n},\dfrac12;\dfrac{5n+2}{4n};-1)\\
 &=\frac{2^{-5/2-1/n}B\left( \frac{n-2}{4n},\frac{n-2}{4n} \right)}{n\cos\left( \frac{n-2}{4n}\pi \right)}
\end{align} 
Among the relations between the central Beta function and the singular values of the elliptic integrals ([here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegralSingularValue.html)), some are linear and the involved trigonometric functions  have a closed form:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{lll}
K(k_1)&=2^{-2}B\left( \frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{4} \right) & a=\frac{1}{4},n=\infty\\
K(k_2) & =2^{-13/4}B\left( \frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{8} \right) & a=\frac{1}{8},n=4\\
K(k_3) &=2^{-4/3}3^{-1/4}B\left( \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3} \right)& a=\frac{1}{3},n=-6\\
K(k_3) & =2^{-5/3}3^{-3/4}B\left( \frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{6} \right) & a=\frac{1}{6},n=6\\
K(k_5) & =2^{-29/20}5^{-3/8}(1+\sqrt{5})^{1/4}\sin (3\pi/20)B\left( \frac{3}{20},\frac{3}{20} \right) & a=\frac{3}{20},n=5\\
K(k_6) &=2^{-47/12}3^{-3/4}\left( \sqrt{2}-1 \right)\left( \sqrt{3} +1\right)B\left( \frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{24} \right) & a=\frac{1}{24},n=\frac{12}{5}\\
K(k_6) & =2^{-43/12}3^{-1/4}\left( \sqrt{3} -1\right)B\left( \frac{5}{24},\frac{5}{24} \right) &a=\frac{5}{24},n=12
\end{array}
\end{equation}
The solutions given in   @TitoPiezasIII answer are retrieved, except for $n=3$. Additional identities of this kind are then 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}nf(n)&=\frac{\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{4} \right)^2}{4\sqrt{\pi}}\\
 f(-6)&=-\frac{2^{-7/3}}{3}B\left( \frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3} \right)\\
 f\left( \frac{12}{5} \right)&=\frac{ 2^{-11/3}\,5B\left( \frac{1}{24},\frac{1}{24} \right)}{3\left( 1+2\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3} \right)^{1/2}}
\end{align}