# On $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n+3\choose n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{3}{2n+1}\right)^4$ and Gieseking's constant

Tags: sequences-and-series, hypergeometric-function, constants

**I. Intro**

While trying to solve [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3081678/) about the function,

$$F(k)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n+3\choose n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{3}{2n+1}\right)^k$$

for $k=3$, I found out *Mathematica* can evaluate this in closed-form for general $k$ using the *generalized hypergeometric function*. Specifically, for $k=3,4$, it involves [Catalan's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalansConstant.html) $G$ and the "similar" [Gieseking's constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GiesekingsConstant.html) $H$,

$$G = \text{Cl}_2\big(\tfrac{\pi}2\big)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(4n+1)^2}-\frac1{(4n+3)^2}\right)=0.91596\dots$$

$$H = \text{Cl}_2\big(\tfrac{\pi}3\big)=\frac{3\sqrt3}4\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac1{(3n+1)^2}-\frac1{(3n+2)^2}\right)=1.01494\dots$$

with Clausen's integral $\text{Cl}_2(\theta)$.

---

**II. Examples**

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n+3\choose n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{3}{2n+1}\right)^3=248-128\sqrt2-30\sqrt2\pi+144\alpha$$
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{2n+3\choose n+1} \left(\frac{1}{2^n}\cdot\frac{3}{2n+1}\right)^4=-1424+720\sqrt3+112\pi+14\pi^3-360H$$

where,

$$\alpha=\,_3F_2\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12;\tfrac32,\tfrac32;\color{red}{\tfrac12}\right) = \frac{4G+\pi\ln2}{4\sqrt2}$$

$$H=\,_3F_2\left(\tfrac12,\tfrac12,\tfrac12;\tfrac32,\tfrac32;\color{red}{\tfrac14}\right)  =\text{Cl}_2\big(\tfrac{\pi}3\big)$$

---

**III. Notes**

1. The constants $G$ and $H$ seem to share certain features. As $\delta=\exp\big(\frac{2G}\pi\big)$ and $\beta=\exp\big(\frac{H}\pi\big)$ they are the *Kneser-Mahler polynomial constants*. (See [p. 231](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=Pl5I2ZSI6uAC&pg=PA233&lpg=PA233&dq=gieseking's%20constant&source=bl&ots=K2lK42ky66&sig=ACfU3U0jcu5ZW1aHWg6EpOkrmwIvZuxZjg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwju09zVh4HgAhWEF4gKHYzwCoYQ6AEwCXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=gieseking's%20constant&f=false) of "Mathematical Constants" by S. Finch.)
2. $G$ is a rational multiple of the volume of an ideal [hyperbolic octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_constant#Uses), while $H$ is the volume of the [hyperbolic Gieseking manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gieseking_manifold).
3. And so on.

---

**IV. Question**

***Q:*** Are there other examples of a series or function $P(k)$ such that it has a closed-form in terms of Catalan's constant $G$ or Gieseking's constant $H$ depending on $k$?

Comment: *Note:* $\enspace$ I think it’s better to discuss the integral of the last part of the equation chain $\enspace$$\displaystyle {}_{m+2}F_{m+1}\left(\frac{1}{2}…\frac{1}{2};\frac{3}{2}…\frac{3}{2};\frac{4}{e^{2x}}\right) = \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{e^{2xn}(2n+1)^{m+1}}\,$$\displaystyle = \frac{e^x}{m!} \sum\limits_{v=0}^m {\binom m v }(-x)^{m-v} \int\limits_x^\infty\frac{t^v~dt}{\sqrt{e^{2t}-4}}\,$ . Perhaps exists literature about $\displaystyle \int\limits_z^\infty t^a\sqrt{\frac{t}{e^t-1}}dt\,$ which could help.

Comment: @user90369: In general, $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x-a}~dx ~=~ \frac{\Gamma(n)\cdot\text{Li}_a(n)}a,~$ so evaluating the integral you suggest might involve [fractional calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus), [incomplete $\Gamma$ functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function), and [polylogarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: In my *note* above is a mistake, the middle series must be $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty {\binom{2n} n} \frac{1}{e^{2xn}(2n+1)^{m+1}}$ . @Lucian : Yes, you are right. And the problem seems to be $\sqrt{.}$ of $\sqrt{e^{2t}-4}$ . I don't know literatur for such types of integrals (right side of the equation chain). ;)